# Styling the enclosing DOM node in Web Components

Tags: javascript, css, web-component

I have defined a type-extension custom element as follows:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var importDoc, myButton;

    importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
    myButton = Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype);

    myButton.createdCallback = function() {
        var template, templateClone, shadow, host;

        template = importDoc.querySelector('#my-button-large-template');
        templateClone = importDoc.importNode(template.content, true);

        host = this;
        shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
        shadow.appendChild(templateClone);
    };

    document.registerElement('my-button', {
        prototype: myButton,
        extends: 'button'
    });

}());
```

The declaration in the DOM looks like this:

```
<button is="my-button">Foo</button>
```

But the button retains the default button styling of the browser (a grey gradient background and an embossed effect).

Can I remove this styling from the element **from within the web component itself**?

Put another way, does the host DOM have to contain styling to neuter the browser stylesheet as applied to web components that extend native elements?

Answer (score 1):

For a `button` element, user agent styles are applied to the element itself (as opposed to its shadow DOM, as with elements like `audio`) so that's where you'd need to style it.  You can, however, style the custom button from inside its shadow DOM with the `:host` selector:

```
myButton.createdCallback = function() {
    var shadow, host;

    host = this;
    shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
    shadow.innerHTML = '<style>:host { color: red; } </style><content></content>';
};
```

Or you can style the custom `button` as you would any normal element, but from inside the `createdCallback`:

```
myButton.createdCallback = function() {
    this.style.color = 'red';
};
```